# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present quando eu faço uma requisição pelo Angular 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, angular, jwt

Eu consigo fazer uma requisição de upload de um arquivo através Postman, mas quando eu faço o pedido do Angular, é retornado o WARN "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"

Segue meu recurso na API feita em Java com Spring boot.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Conteudo> publicaConteudo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException 
{
   /* ANYTHING */
   return ResponseEntity.ok(new Conteudo());
}
```

E meu serviço em Angular. Estou usando o JWT, mas também estou tentando fazer a requisição usando o HttpClient.

```
upload(file: File, conteudo: Conteudo): Promise<any> {
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', file, file.name);

  /* USING JWT
  return this.http.post(this.conteudoUrl, formData)
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => response.json());
  */
  let h1 = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
  localStorage.getItem('token'));
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST',this.conteudoUrl, formData, {
     headers: h1
  });
  return this.httpClient.request(req).toPromise();
}
```

Eu consigo fazer a requisição pelo postman normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei muitas soluções que eu encontrei, como criar um Bean MultipartResolver e etc, mas nenhuma solução resolveu meu problema e o que eu acho mais interessante é que ele funciona normalmente no Postman.

Cabeçalho da requisição no navegador que está causando o problema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cabeçalho do postman no qual a requisição funciona corretamente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já olhou na aba networks como que a requisição está indo ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos eu olhei.. E comparei com a do postman. Não consegui visualizar nada que possa estar causando esse problema. Vou tirar print e colocar na descrição.

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos Coloquei os cabeçalhos na descrição

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver? estou com o mesmo problema.